# How to get the value of a specific key in multi-dimensional array PHP

Tags: php

I have some arrays, below are 2 examples of those arrays. I wanna get the value of the key **mode**. We don't know at which index those arrays are. I tried the following:

```
$text1 = array(
           'type'=>'balance',
           'lang'=> array(
                  'text'=>array(
                      'en'=>array('mode'=>'ussd', 'tet'=>'Your balance is'),
                      'ru'=>array('mode'=>'ussd', 'tet'=>'vash balance'),
                  ),
               ),
           );

$text2 = array(
           'type'=>'balance',
           'lang'=> array(
                  'text'=>array(
                      'en'=>array(
                          'success'=>array(
                               'mode'=>'ussd', 
                               'tet'=>'Your balance is'), 
                          'error'=>array(
                               'mode'=>'ussd',
                               'tet'=>'Your balance is err')
                             ),
                      'ru'=>array(
                           'success'=>array(
                                'mode'=>'ussd',
                                'tet'=>'vash balans'), 
                            'error'=>array(
                                'mode'=>'ussd', 
                                'tet'=>'vash balans is err'
                                )
                            ),
                  ),
               ),
           );          

function GetKey($key, $search)
{
    foreach ($search as $array)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $array))
        {
            return $array[$key];
        }
    }

    return false;
}

$tmp = GetKey('mode' , $text1);
echo $tmp;
```

This returns: 
Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 27

According to php.net: array_key_exists() will search for the keys in the first dimension only. **Nested keys in multidimensional arrays will not be found**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will call itself recursively until it finds the first key, and will return the value. It could potentially be expanded it to collect all values, or even return an array of indexes to each one.

```
function GetKey($key, $array) {
    if (is_array($array)) {
        foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
            if ($k == $key) {
                return $v;
            } elseif (is_array($v)) {
                return GetKey($key, $v);
            }
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Edit**: find all values. The function does not return now, just keeps pushing the results to an array that all of the recursive have in their scope, by using `global`.

```
function GetKey($key, $array) {
    global $results;

    if (is_array($array)) {
        foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
            if ($k == $key) {
                $results[] = $v;
            } elseif (is_array($v)) {
                GetKey($key, $v);
            }
        }
    }
}

$results = array();
GetKey('mode', $text1);
// $results is now: ['ussd', 'ussd']

$results = array();
GetKey('mode', $text2);
// $results is now: ['ussd', 'ussd', 'ussd', 'ussd']
```

Comment: Yep, collecting all values if they are different would be good.